# print number using comma

Tags: c#, .net

I use double number and I want to display only two digit before "." and two digit after "." I write this code but not true in c#

```
double x = 37.567891;
Console.WriteLine("x={0:D2}", x);
```

Comment: What should happen with `137.567891`?

Comment: In title it is mentioned using comma. Better clarify how input should look like.

Comment: I guess you could say "decimal separator". For me as a German it is also hard to say "decimal separator" instead of "comma" most of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using decimal format. It should be:

```
double x = 37.567891;
Console.WriteLine("x={0:F2}", x % 100);
```

You could also use

```
double x = 37.567891;
Console.WriteLine("x={0}", (x % 100).ToString("##.##"));
```

The "modulo" operator (`%`) makes sure only the last to digits before the decimal separator are output.

If you want to print `123.456` as `123.45`, remove the `% 100` in the respective places.

Answer (score 1):

There're ***two*** possibilities when you formatting *floating point values* (e.g. `Double`):

You can specify number of *all the digits* (***4*** in your case)

```
  // for  37.567891 it will be 37.57
  // for 137.567891 it will be 137.6
  double x = 37.567891;
  Console.WriteLine("x={0:G4}", x);
```

You can specify number of *digits after decimal separator* (***2*** in your case)

```
  // for  37.567891 it will be 37.57
  // for 137.567891 it will be 137.57
  double x = 37.567891;
  Console.WriteLine("x={0:F2}", x);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
double x = 37.567891;
Console.WriteLine(x.ToString("0.##"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double x = 37.567891;
Console.WriteLine(x.ToString("N")); //output 37.57
Console.WriteLine(x.ToString("0.00")); //output 37.57
```

You can also print culture independent value:

```
Console.WriteLine(x.ToString("00.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); //output 37.57
```

See MSDN Reference on [Custom Numeric Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx).